# How do I make this Func work with Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, func

I have an abstract, generic repository class that encapsulates a lot of logic, and it is able to do that because it knows how to isolate a unique *data row*, thanks to its *KeyCompare* property, which is injected into the repository's constructor:

```
Func<T, T, bool> KeyCompare { get; }
```

The role of this property is to tell the base class what fields to use to fetch a unique record - sometimes it's just "Id" and KeyCompare can be assigned like this (passed to constructor):

```
(item1, item2) => item1.Id == item2.Id
```

However it also gives me the flexibility of using Linq to SQL classes that have keys that span several columns, like this:

```
(item1, item2) => item1.Field1 == item2.Field1 && item1.Field2 == item2.Field2
```

And this works very well in the unit tests, but only **because I'm testing with a mock repo that uses Linq to Object**.

Production code uses Linq to SQL and since I've been told my `KeyCompare` property won't behave as expected (because the `Func` won't be translated to SQL), that I should be using an `Expression` instead. So I started googling around (and apparently `Func` won't be translated to SQL), and saw many examples, but nothing like what I'm doing (is that a sign of something?).

The way I'm using the `Func` is as follows:

```
public T Item(T item)
{
    return (_items.SingleOrDefault(e => KeyCompare(e, item));
}
```

I was told to implement the method like this (with `KeyCompare` being an `Expression`):

```
public T Item(T item)
{
    return (_items.SingleOrDefault(KeyCompare);
}
```

But this won't compile (.SingleOrDefault wants a `Func`, not an `Expression`) and, if it did, it wouldn't be using the *item* value that I need to give it in order to do what I intend.

I'm injecting this `Func` into the repo's constructor with Ninject; here's how I bind the `KeyCompare` constructor argument:

```
.WithConstructorArgument("keyCompare", (Func<MockEntity, MockEntity, bool>)((item1, item2) => item1.Id == item2.Id));
```

So I'm stuck. **How do I make this work with Linq to SQL**?

The alternative, if I drop this `KeyCompare` property in the base class, is to write redundant code every time I need to implement a concrete repository, which I'd like to avoid. With this `KeyCompare` property, I only need to write the code that's specific to each repository type to implement a new one, and I like that.

This post has the complete [original - it has changed since] code for the abstract repository class I'm talking about: [Can Ninject use an anonymous delegate (func) as a ConstructorArgument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096229/can-ninject-use-an-anonymous-delegate-func-as-a-constructorargument/16096309#16096309)

**EDIT**

[LINQ-to-SQL : Convert Func<T, T, bool> to an Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321329/linq-to-sql-convert-funct-t-bool-to-an-expressionfunct-t-bool) has an interesting answer and a pinpoint accurate title (and I really wonder how I could have missed that one in my research). It actually answers this question with an excellent, detailed answer that I'm going to try in a moment.

> The usage is now a little weird, since this is a curried lambda.
>   Instead of passing (x,y) => ... you will be passing x => y => ....

I'm sure the solution works (it's quite clever), **but it does not explain *why* passing (x,y) needs a backflip and a triple axel to perform.** What's the deal with two inputs? If Linq to Objects can pull this off, what is it exactly that's preventing Linq to SQL from doing the same?

Comment: If you cast your query to an `IQueryable` using `.AsQueryable()` can you use an expression?

Comment: @EricAndres right, my `ListRepository<T>` is using a `List<T>` so using `.AsQueryable()` does work. But I still can't use the two `T` arguments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got all tests to pass - both with the LinqToObject "mock" repo and the LinqToSql "production" repo (the latter being an automated integration test). Here's how:

From the answer on this post: [LINQ-to-SQL : Convert Func<T, T, bool> to an Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321329/linq-to-sql-convert-funct-t-bool-to-an-expressionfunct-t-bool), grab the code to create the `PartialApplier` static class whose role is to rewrite the expression on the fly (from what I grasped).

I then made both `ListRepository` and `DataRepository` derive from `RepositoryBase` which implements `IRepository<T>`. Here's the repo class:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    public abstract IQueryable<T> Select();
    public abstract void Save(T item);
    public abstract void Delete(T item);
    public abstract void Delete(IEnumerable<T> items);

    public virtual Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> KeyCompare { get; private set; }
    public virtual int Count { get { return Select().Count(); } }

    protected RepositoryBase(Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> keyCompare)
    {
        KeyCompare = keyCompare;
    }

    public virtual T Item(T item)
    {
        var applied = PartialApplier.PartialApply(KeyCompare, item);
        var result = (Select().SingleOrDefault(applied));

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A method that updates the non-key fields of an existing entity with those of specified <see cref="item"/>.
    /// Called by the <see cref="Save"/> method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="existing">The existing record to update.</param>
    /// <param name="item">A <see cref="T"/> object containing the values to update <see cref="existing"/> object with.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract void UpdateExisting(T existing, T item);

    /// <summary>
    /// A method that saves all specified items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">The entities to be saved.</param>
    public virtual void Save(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Save(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The `ListRepository` was no issue, but needed a bit of reworking to properly derive from `RepositoryBase`:

```
/// <summary>
/// A non-persistent repository implementation for mocking the repository layer.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class ListRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly List<T> _items = new List<T>();

    public ListRepository(IEnumerable<T> items, Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> keyCompare)
        : base(keyCompare)
    {
        _items.AddRange(items);
    }

    public override IQueryable<T> Select()
    { 
        return _items.AsQueryable(); 
    }

    public override void Save(T item)
    {
        var existing = Item(item);
        if (existing != null)
        {
            _items.Remove(item);
        }

        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public override void Save(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Save(item);
        }
    }

    public override void Delete(T item)
    {
        _items.Remove(item);
    }

    public override void Delete(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Delete(Item(item));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not implemented.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="existing"></param>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    protected override void UpdateExisting(T existing, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // list repo just wipes existing data
    }
}
```

And then the `DataRepository` could look like this:

```
public abstract class DataRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>
    where T : class
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public DataRepository(DataContext context, Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> keyCompare)
        : base(keyCompare)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override IQueryable<T> Select()
    {
        return _context.GetTable<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A method that updates an existing item or creates a new one, as needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The entity containing the values to be saved.</param>
    public override void Save(T item)
    {
        var existing = Item(item);
        if (existing != null)
        {
            UpdateExisting(existing, item);
        }
        else
        {
            _context.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(item);
        }

        _context.SubmitChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A method that deletes specified item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    public override void Delete(T item)
    {
        var existing = Item(item);
        if (existing != null)
        {
            _context.GetTable<T>().DeleteOnSubmit(existing);
        }

        _context.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public override void Delete(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Delete(item);
        }
    }

    protected override void UpdateExisting(T existing, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // must override in derived classes - not obvious I know
    }
}
```

So, given a DataContext with only a simple object (called `DataRepositoryIntegrationTest` in this case), we can create an implementation to test it all out:

```
public class TestRepository : DataRepository<DataRepositoryIntegrationTest>
{
    public TestRepository(DataContext context)
        : base(context,  (item1, item2) => item1.Id == item2.Id)
    { }

    protected override void UpdateExisting(DataRepositoryIntegrationTest existing, DataRepositoryIntegrationTest item)
    {
        existing.Value = item.Value;
        existing.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And then the tests can be written:

```
[TestClass]
public class DataRepositoryTests
{
    private IRepository<DataRepositoryIntegrationTest> _repo;
    private static DataContext _context;

    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void CleanUp()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public DataRepositoryTests()
    {
        _context = new DataContext(Settings.Default.IntegrationTestConnectionString);
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitRepository()
    {
        _context.ExecuteCommand("truncate table dbo.IntegrationTest");
        _context.ExecuteCommand("insert into dbo.IntegrationTest ([Value], [DateInserted]) values ('Test1', getdate())");
        _context.ExecuteCommand("insert into dbo.IntegrationTest ([Value], [DateInserted]) values ('Test2', getdate())");
        _context.ExecuteCommand("insert into dbo.IntegrationTest ([Value], [DateInserted]) values ('Test3', getdate())");
        _repo = new TestRepository(_context);
    }

    private DataRepositoryIntegrationTest CreateItem(string value)
    {
        return new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest { Value = value, DateInserted = DateTime.Now };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldInsertItem()
    {
        // arrange
        var item = CreateItem("Test.ShouldInsert1");
        var expectedCount = _repo.Count + 1;

        // act
        _repo.Save(item);
        var actualCount = _repo.Count;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldInsertItems()
    {
        // arrange
        var count = _repo.Count;
        var items = new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest[] { 
            CreateItem("Test.ShouldInsert1"),
            CreateItem("Test.ShouldInsert2")};
        var expected = count + items.Length;

        // act
        _repo.Save(items);
        var actual = _repo.Count;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldUpdateItem()
    {
        if (_repo.Count == 0) throw new AssertInconclusiveException("ShouldUpdateItem requires an existing item.");

        // arrange
        var item = _repo.Item(new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest { Id = 1 });
        var expected = "updated";
        item.Value = expected;

        // act
        _repo.Save(item);
        var result = _repo.Item(new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest { Id = item.Id });
        var actual = result.Value;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldDeleteItem()
    {
        if (_repo.Count == 0) throw new AssertInconclusiveException("ShouldUpdateItem requires an existing item.");

        // arrange
        var item = _repo.Item(new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest { Id = 1 });
        var expected = _repo.Count - 1;

        // act
        _repo.Delete(item);
        var actual = _repo.Count;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldDeleteItems()
    {
        if (_repo.Count < 2) throw new AssertInconclusiveException("ShouldUpdateItem requires 2 existing items.");

        // arrange
        var items = new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest[] {
            new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest { Id = 1 },
            new DataRepositoryIntegrationTest { Id = 2 }};
        var expected = _repo.Count - items.Count();

        // act
        _repo.Delete(items);
        var actual = _repo.Count;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

**And they ALL pass!**

Comment: The only itchy spot (that I can see... for now), is that I have abstract classes deriving from an abstract class, which means concrete repo implementations can no longer automatically override the `UpdateExisting` method, because there's no such thing as an `abstract override` way of implementing an abstract method (bit like abstract implementation of an interface method but for an abstract class method)... but I can live with it.